# translation in carmen-rails gem how to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

I use carmen-rails gem in my app and i search a solution to translate countries and sub-regions in other language than English but i have no idea, in documentation it's not clear, it just says :

> Using this library will automatically set Carmen to use Rails' built-in I18n functionality. This means that changing some configuration should be done through Rails and not Carmen. For example, adding paths for additional locale files should be done inside config/application.rb:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a matter of adding the correct key structure on a locale file. eg:

```
---
en:
  world:
    br:
      common_name: !!null 
      name: Brazil
      official_name: Federative Republic of Brazil
```

Carmen documentation seems to be a place to look https://github.com/jim/carmen#localization